# How to select volume mountpoint in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I need to mount volume `/path/a` from one container to `/path/b` in another container, but according to [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#volumes) only `HOST:CONTAINER` or `HOST:CONTAINER:ro` allowed to write in `VOLUMES` section.

Any ideas how to do that in docker-compose.yml?

Comment: create a volume on the host and mount both containers on there ?

Comment: I have data in container1 on  /path/a and want to access to it in container2 on /path/b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a volume on the host with a bind mount for both containers.

Example:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/shared-volume
docker run --name container1 -v /mnt/shared-volume:/path/a mycontainer
docker run --name container2 -v /mnt/shared-volume:/path/b mycontainer
```

Same with `docker-compose.yml`:

```
volumes:
 - /mnt/shared-volume:/path/a
```

And for the other container:

```
volumes:
 - /mnt/shared-volume:/path/b
```

**Alternative solution:**

Create a data volume container!

Example:

```
docker run --name datacontainer -v /mnt/shared-volume mycontainer /bin/true
docker run --name container1 --volumes-from datacontainer mycontainer
docker run --name container2 --volumes-from datacontainer mycontainer
```

Comment: As I ansvered before I have data in container1 on /path/a and want to access to it in container2 on /path/b. If I understand you, data should be at /mnt/shared-volume?

Comment: I don't think that's possible without restarting container1 and doing a bind mount to a host volume which the other container can mount. Or you could do a separate data volume container. Am I wrong here? Anyone?

Comment: Please see: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/ for futher reference. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Maybe there is another way to mount or just copy /pycharm_helpers folder form [this container](https://hub.docker.com/r/pcdocker/pycharm_helpers/) to /root/.pycharm_helpers in mine?

Comment: Edited my answer with instructions on creating a data volume container. However, this causes all the volumes on container1 and container2 to be shared.

Comment: I found simpler solution for my problem, without mounting volumes. I just create container. Details here :[https://bitbucket.org/snippets/linevich/EE57M](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/linevich/EE57M)

Comment: I still don't understand what you've achieved with that. I guess I just don't understand the original problem.

Comment: Maybe. Original problem was: I need to access `/pycharm_helpres` folder from existig image avaliable in Docker Hub in my container at `/root/.pycharm_helpres` path. Thanks for your answer it may helps somebody, I mark question as solved.